# Self assembling of hardware for bitcoin mining

Tags: asic, mining-hardware

Are there any guides or material available for helping us build dedicated ASIC hardware for bitcoin mining .

Comment: -1 you are supposed to try to find your answer by yourself before asking the question here...

Comment: I am indeed looking for hardware plans \schematics for contracting ASIC and i cant find them.And i have done the research

Comment: _"The non-recurring engineering (NRE) cost of an ASIC can run into the millions of dollars."_ [wikipedia, introduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application-specific_integrated_circuit). I'm sorry, but if you didn't even read wikipedia, just for starters, you should seriously revisit your searching strategies.

Comment: DBTN, Lohoris--it's not that crazy that someone wouldn't know exactly where to look for info about building ASICs.

Answer (score 6):

You can't build ASIC hardware yourself. It costs hundreds of thousands of dollars to develop an ASIC and, by definition, you can't buy them off the shelf. (The "AS" stands for "Application Specific", that is, it must be designed for a particular purpose.)

Comment: does design cost more or the process of making ASIC? and are there any schematics made available to put to production those who have the infrastructure?

Comment: These days, the single biggest expense is typically the one-time cost of the production mask which would be around $1.5 million for a 65nm ASIC. (It is possible to get this down to $500,000 if you can share mask space with other people also trying to cut ASIC costs though the logistics of such sharing can be awkward.)

Comment: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=76351.0 will this help ?

Answer (score 5):

Try this site for schematics:  https://github.com/BitSyncom/avalon-ref

If you know the answer, don't be a jerk.  Just answer the question.  It helps to have answers/discussions for the same issue in many different places.  This is one of the first pages that comes up when you search "asic schematics"

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mining_rig
And this: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mining_hardware_comparison

Comment: asic hardware? howto?

Comment: ASIC is the short form for Application-specific integrated circuit, its very unlikely that any private person that is asking for guide material is able to build a BTC mining ASIC...

Comment: You should use a little more Google to answear your questions on your self before asking them here...

Answer (score 0):

ASIC mining chips are currently being sold by companies such as Butterfly labs which are less expensive than the fully assembled hardware. As for implementing- you'll have to search. I haven't had any luck.

Answer (score -2):

ANYONE can contract board work, if he can do the layout himself. There are several board layout programs that will let you do this. 
There are plenty of board manufacturers that produce your boards, if you do the layout and send it to them. Some will even check your work to make sure it will work, for an extra fee, if you tell them your intentions. Signed contracts will keep your stuff safe from duplication. And if you keep some information to yourself, such as the finished product, it will keep it even safer.
All you need is the pin-outs of the chips you are going to use, know how to write the firmware for it, and there are some sellers/resellers that will sell you their mining chips (ASICs I mean). If they do sell them to you, they will surely give you the information on how to hook them up (pin-outs), or they would be useless to sell.

It IS true that actually having an ASIC made will be more than difficult, but if THEY can do it, so can you.
Right now (11-2013), there are chips available to use in building your machine(s). However, these are mostly older model chips (128ns or higher, usually), so you will have to use a lot of them to get anything up to today's par.
Keeping this in mind, there are usually several things that are static on the pins, such as power, communications to and from the chip, and auxiliary pins for connecting capacitors, resistors, timing clocks (crystals), used to control the circuit and chip, what speed it runs, etc. A 128 pin chip, needs most, if not all of those lines connected to something.

Comment: This answer contains some interesting points, but would benefit from more specific information, such as concrete examples for layout programs. Edited for spelling, and removed the anecdotal and abusive passages.

Answer (score -3):

Let's take a look at this from a basic level.  Coins of any type are mined through complex math problems being solved by various devices that all have exactly  3 things in common.
1. They are powered by some sort of processor (or multiple processors) that perform the calculations.
2. They all have some sort of memory or storage area where the program for solving the problems resides.

1. They all access the internet so that they can actively mine coins.

Let's see.  Computers can do it! (cpu mining) Graphic Cards do it!  (gpu Mining), do you see a pattern developing here?  With Chips being amazingly cheap and readily available, and code being freely shared via the net, It is entirely plausible that one could develop and build coin miner.

It's called Hacking, or at least it used to be.  Taking stuff apart to see how it works, researching things to see if you can do it yourself or better yet, come up with a more efficient way of doing it.

You don't have to spend thousands of dollars to devise a way to make your own ASIC *or similar device*.  You just need the dedication, drive, and motivation to do so.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's just a bad answer. One with the proper skills could write a program from a CPU, GPU or FPGA to mine bitcoins. But since such programs are already available, that would just be doing for the sake of doing; they're not what the question asked about; and they're vastly inferior (by a factor of 100) to dedicated chips ("ASIC"). And ASIC are something that a hobbyist *cannot* do in his garage, it requires professional design and a million dollar in masks.